# Python Calculation

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a method `different(self, other)` that returns an integer that represents the # of days between self(one calendar date) and other(another calendar date).

Comment: Where does that `Date` class come from? Why are you not using `datetime.date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared your `Date` class with us, but [Python already provides one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects), complete with methods to calculate date differences:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> a = date(2014,11,10)
>>> b = date(2014,12,24)
>>> b-a
datetime.timedelta(44)
>>> (b-a).days   # if you need the number of days as an integer
44
```

I usually prefer `datetime.datetime`, though - it provides greater accuracy and more methods to manipulate dates:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime(2014,11,10)  # works just the same, but you can also
>>> b = datetime(2014,12,24)  # add hours/minutes/seconds etc.
>>> b-a
datetime.timedelta(44)
>>> (b-a).days
44
```

Comment: Date calculation is *hard*. Why reinvent the wheel?  Or are you just doing this as a learning experience?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `datetime.date`

```
def diff(a, b):
    adate = datetime.date(a.year, a.month, a.day)
    bdate = datetime.date(b.year, b.month, b.day)
    return abs(adate.toordinal() - bdate.toordinal())
```

you can get this for free in your Date class if you inherit from `datetime.date (check out the ttcal module I wrote for a time-tracking app for an example: https://github.com/datakortet/dk/blob/master/dk/ttcal.py#L471)